# How To Use Same LinearLayout In Different Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I want to use same LinearLayout in different activities. Selected LinearLayout's id in picture is previewLinear. What I want to do is, use previewLinear in a different activity. I have A and B activities. Firstly I do some changes for previewLinear in activity A (adding border, slice it to pieces etc.) programmatically and I want to copy whole previewLinear to B activity.

pencerebol.xml
[image]

What I tried is;

A Activity: (container is static)

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.pencerebol);
...
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewLinear);
        container.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
```

B Activity:

```
...
setContentView(R.layout.pencerebol);
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.previewLinear);
container = A.container; // I know that this line is completely wrong but this is what i want to do.
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: you can simply setcontentview to the same xml layout, what happened when you did the above code, post your logCat and tell us what is happening!

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. It just gives me the empty xml, I want to get LinearLayout with changes done in activity A.

Comment: Do you want the same layout or a copy of the layout?

Comment: `<LinearLayout` `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/pencerebol">`


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="100"/>
</LinearLayout>
This is my pencerebol.xml and I want to copy second LinearLayout with changes. So I want to copy LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right you want to make LinearLayout from B activity look same as in A activity.

You can create method in A activity

```
static void createLinearLayout(LinearLayout layout){
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
    ...
}
```

Then call it in B activity

```
A.createLinearLayout(container);
```

Comment: I tried to slice to pieces the container. For it, I've already have a function called createWindow. But it takes 3 parameters and I'm not able to store whole parameters. Thats why I can't call this function from activity B. That's why I'm trying to copy it and not using a static function.

Comment: Before show whole code, i tried this too, can you explain the error please?

In activity A:
   ` public static LinearLayout getContainer() { 
        return container;
    }`

In activity B:
`container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.previewLinear);
        container.addView(GenelPencereBolActivity.getContainer());`

And this is my logcat:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Dauezevy It's because your `container` from A activity already has a parent. It's added in your layout  xml.

Comment: So this is not a solution, true ?

Comment: Obvisously not. If you want your layout from B look exactly like layout from A, which u styled programmatically, you can use my answer. Also you can style your layout in xml like @blueware suggested.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try both solutions (by editing my whole code) and accept ur answers if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<include>` property in your XML files, you only create one layout and include it in your other activities/fragments, this is an example of that:

create a xml for your previewLinear layout, name it as:

> layout_preview_linear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/previewLinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
```

and then in your activity A or B, you can include it as the following:

> activity_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/activity_a_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/previewLayout"
            layout="@layout/layout_preview_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

You also can use that layout in your JAVA code as well, hope this will help you.

Comment: I'll try this and edit my answer.

edit: It gives me empty LinearLayout again

Comment: If it works with you, please accept as the correct answer, otherwise, let me know so I help you much more

Comment: Is there any usage like; id="@id/previewLinear" in include ? Because I  just want to copy previewLinear from pencerebol.xml. Not whole pencerebol.xml

Comment: id="@id/previewLinear" is important to make a reference for it in your activity, for example: LinearLayout previewLinear = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.previewLinear);

Comment: Glad to help you my friend